# how to apply if Condition in rdlc report to display "Yes" if the column return true value and if it display false return "No"

Tags: report, rdlc

i am working on rdlc report , i have a column in rdlc report , and i want if there is true value , return me "YES"
and if there is false return "NO"
i have tried the following code but it not working

```
=iif(Field!Application.value)="True","Yes","No"))
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it was like this

```
=IIf(Field!Application.Value = true,"yes","no")
```

1) 'V' is supposed to be capital
2) parenthesis should be at the end.

Comment: Field needs to be Fields

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **IIf** command:

```
=IIf(<Expression as Boolean>, <TruePart as Object>, <FalsePart as Object>) as Object
```

Like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!Application.Value = true, "Yes", "No")
```

This works to me, bye!